# Unable to see specflow features in Item list

Tags: visual-studio-2015, specflow

After added extensions and installed specflow package, Unable to see specflow features in the Item list.

[image: See the below image]

Comment: Could you try and manually install the extension from this [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TechTalkSpecFlowTeam.SpecFlowforVisualStudio2015)

Comment: https://specflow.org/getting-started/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the SpecFlow packages are installed through **NuGet Package Manager**. It requires to install the SpecFlow for Visual Studio extension as below.

1. Open your Visual Studio
2. Click on the Extensions Tab, which will display the Manage Extensions window

   [image: SpecFlow]
3. On the Right hand Search bar type as *specflow*
4. **SpecFlow for Visual Studio** would be displayed with download button. (Since I already installed it is displayed the tick symbol)
5. Click on the **Download** button and install the extension.
6. Now get back to your project, Right click the **Features folder** (*I assume you have created this folder already if not create it*) **--> Add --> New item**

   [image]
7. Click on **SpecFlow** category and select the **SpecFlow Feature File** option to create the feature file

   [image: SpecFlow-2]